# mod_rewrite rule: if URL contains a certain string to orginal

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My client keeps editing the structure of the navigation in the website, which is leading to some mod_rewrite issues. How could i make this rule in apache:

the actual ur is

```
/AuthCont?FORMSGROUP_ID__=AuthenticationFG&__START_TRAN_FLAG__=Y&FG_BUTTONS__=LOAD&ACTION.LOAD=Y&AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=1&T_ID=ND
```

but if user manually changes `AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=1` to `AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=2` or `AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=3` it should rewrite to actual `AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=1` kindly help

Answer (score 0):

From: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

> **Modifying the Query String:** Change any single instance of val in the query string to other_val when accessing /path. Note that %1 and %2 are back-references to the matched part of the regular expression in the previous RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)val(.*)$
RewriteRule /path /path?%1other_val%2
```

So you could try for example:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)LOGIN_FLAG=2(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)LOGIN_FLAG=3(.*)$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)LOGIN_FLAG=4(.*)$
 # and so on for all the numbers...
 # then:
 RewriteRule /AuthCont /AuthCont?%1LOGIN_FLAG=1%2
```

**EDIT**

hrmm okay try this:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)LOGIN_FLAG=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your_domain_here.com/AuthCont?FORMSGROUP_ID__=AuthenticationFG&__START_TRAN_FLAG__=Y&FG_BUTTONS__=LOAD&ACTION.LOAD=Y&AuthenticationFG.LOGIN_FLAG=1&T_ID=ND? [L]
```

Comment: I've had problems in the past with trying to re-write large query strings--this is largely dependent on your hosting provider. Try creating a test use case with small URI strings to be sure this is not the problem. Also, verify that you have the Apache mod_rewrite directive enabled.

Comment: Also, in the second example the `?` at the end is needed at the end of the rewrite rule so the original navigation is entirely disregarded